# Silverstripe 3 list all templates (.ss - files) in a specific folder

Tags: php, templates, arraylist, directory, silverstripe

Is there a ready made function in Silverstripe 3 to get all templates living in a specific folder to have them in an Arraylist?

if not, anybody done that before?

my goal is to choose the template from a dropdown or radio-button-set.

or should i do it with something like...

```
$files = glob("/path/to/directory/*.ss");
```

thanks. sepp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userforms module [does this](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/blob/4.6/code/model/recipients/UserDefinedForm_EmailRecipient.php#L427-L448) to display a list of possible recipient email templates. Here's the relevant part:

```php
$templates = [];
$finder = new SS_FileFinder();
$finder->setOption('name_regex', '/^.*\.ss$/');
$found = $finder->find(BASE_PATH . '/path/to/directory');
foreach ($found as $key => $value) {
    $template = pathinfo($value);
    $templates[$template['filename']] = $template['filename'];
}
```